# How to overwrite core/libraries/vendor template with child theme

Tags: plugins, child-theme, template-hierarchy

A theme that I am using is overwriting the woocommerce templates with files in `theme/core/libraries/vendor/woocommerce/templates` folder.

I tried to overwrite some minor stuff by following the best practices - I placed the updated file in the same folder structure as the parent theme, and I also tried by placing it in `theme_child/woocommerce/` folder as it's expected for plugin overwrites.

None of these gave me the desired outcome. The only way is to change the parent theme, which I want to prevent if possible.

My end goal is to change the HTML output which as far as I can see is in the template and not in any specific function that I can easily replace. I am not experienced in WP development so I might be missing some obscure detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the same structure in your child theme.

child_theme/core/libraries/vendor/woocommerce/templates

Comment: I mentioned that this was the first thing that I tried and it did not help.